# Binding the combobox values for an empty datatemplate of a bound itemscontrol wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have an itemscontrol that is bound to a datasource via LINQ. I am trying to create a repeatable control that a) displays the records returned from the LINQ query and b) allows the user to add a new row.

I have 2 collections:

a) fareItemCollection this contains a collection of fareItem objects which include a fareDate and PermitNumber.

b) permitNumbers this is an Ienumerable

I can display the fare items in a repeatable itemsControl. I want to be able to show the permit number as a drop down list (i.e. combobox) of permitNumbers with the permitNumber for that fare selected. The user should be able to select a different permit number to assign to that fareItem if they wish.

I have no problem with retrieving the required data via LINQ, it is how I bind the permitNumbers data in the combobox that I am struggling with. I understand how to bind a dataset to a combobox normally but not when it is within an items control bound to another source. Is this even possible or is there another way to approach this?

Here's my xaml so far - Note PermitNumbers is the name of my iEnumerable which is a public property within the window's class:

```
    <ItemsControl Name="fareItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
             <TextBlock>Date</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
             <TextBlock>Driver</TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding FareDate, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yy\},  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource FormFieldTextBoxStyle}">    
    </TextBlock>
         </StackPanel>
         <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PermitNumbers,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>
          </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <ItemsControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">                                                
                     <TextBlock>Date</TextBlock>
                  </StackPanel>
                  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">                                                                       
                     <TextBlock>Driver</TextBlock>
                  </StackPanel>
                  <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                     <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding FareDate, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource datePickerStyle}"> </DatePicker>
                  </StackPanel>
                  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PermitNumbers,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>
                   </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Thanks
Kay

---

Further information:
The following is the fareObject that I am using within my fareObjectsCollection that is bound to the fareItemsControl above:

```
public class FareProxy
    {

  DateTime _fareDate;
        public DateTime FareDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _fareDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _fareDate = value;
            }
        }

 IEnumerable<string> _permitNumbers;
        public IEnumerable<string> PermitNumbers
        {
            get
            {
                return _permitNumbers;
            }
            set
            {
                _permitNumbers = value;
            }
        }

      }
```

For each fare item the date displays correctly within the items control but the permitNumbers won't bind to the permitNumbers combobox. I tried to create a permitNumbers property within the class of the window I am using and load the permitNumbers by setting the source path of the comboBox to the permitNumbers property as suggested in the post below but this didn't work either.

Comment: *it is how I bind the permitNumbers data in the combobox that I am struggling with*... care to give us a better description of your problem? I have no idea what you want.

Comment: @Sheridan apologies Sheridan - it's complicated - i've tried to give you a bit more info above. Basically if I just had a combobox I wanted to bind the permitNumbers collection to I'd be fine but because the combobox sits within an itemsControl that is bound to a different source I can't bind the permitNumbers to it.

Comment: Is it possible to have a bound itemsControl that contains a dropDown list of values in a comboBox that is also dataBound?

Comment: OK - I just figured out that I can create a new fareObject add it to the fareItemCollection and bind the fareItemCollection as shown by @Sheridan. If anyone has any suggestions for a better way of doing this, please feel free to comment. I've become a bit code blind to this issue now so may not have come up with the best possible solution!

Thanks for all your help.

Kay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few changes. First things first... whichever `Window` or `UserControl` that your `fareItemsControl ItemsControl` is in has an object set as its `DataContext`... I think that you've just set the `fareItemCollection` as the `DataContext`. That's your first mistake.

That collection property is in some class. Move your `permitNumbers` collection as a property to that same class. Now set an instance of that class (that contains both collection properties) as the `DataContext`.

Now, you'll need to update your `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property:

```
<ItemsControl Name="fareItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding fareItemCollection}" ... />
```

For the final part, @ethicallogics was correct to point out that you'd need to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to access your `permitNumbers` collection from inside a `DataTemplate`. However, he omitted the essential `DataContext` part. So the correct `RelativeSource Path` should be something more like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.permitNumbers, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" IsEditable="True"></ComboBox>
```

This means that the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is looking for a property named `permitNumbers` in the object that is set as the `DataContext` for the parent `Window`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks - This works perfectly when I have a fareObject within my fareItemCollection. The problem I have is when my fareObjectCollection is empty, I want to allow my user to add a new fareObject to the collection. I want them to be able to select a permitnumber from the comboBox where the permitNumbers are bound from a datasource. This is my problem, not sure how to bind that permitNumbers collection to an empty row in the itemsControl. Think I might be coming at it the wrong way when adding new items to the collection...